# Using "by" for non-actors

Tags: prepositions

I wrote:

> In most treebanks, sentences are annotated either (**by or with** ?) dependency structure or phrase structure depending on the syntax properties of the language.

*The dependency structure* is not the doer of the annotation, can I still use "by"? Should I only use "by" for the actor of the action?

Comment: First off, "by" (or whatnot) needs to precede "either".  And actually I find that most often the preposition "with" is used with the verb "annotate".

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to reserve "by" for the actor. For instance, Legos can be sorted *by color*.

My mind does make a very subtle distinction between the connotations of "annotated by" versus "annotated with", but it's hard to express, and I'd really need a larger segment of context to be sure that "by" is acceptable. So I'd stay safe and stick with "with".

**EDIT:** Your comment has sharpened my thinking on this. I think that when you could use "based on" you can use "by". For instance, Legos can be sorted *based on* color. I.e. when you're making a distinction *based on* some criteria then you could use "by".

Comment: Thanks, then when we are not sure if "by" is applicable, we'd better use "with" or "using"?

Comment: "**Annotated by**" is used when something or someone does the annotation or when talking about some process the result of which is the annotation.  If I annotate your text, your text would be "annotated by Victor".  Similar verb: "decorate".